# use python to call Dll while dll return string*(or char**)

Tags: python, c++, dll

I want to use python call C++, so I build a new Dll-project.I can load DLL successfully! And I want to print `string[]` in python. But now I just can print `int`, `char*` (as show in below, it is: "I love myPan!").
So, how can I print other args?

hello.h

```
    extern "C"
    {   HELLO_API int IntAdd(int, int);
        HELLO_API char* show();
        HELLO_API char** call_char();
        HELLO_API string* call_pic(char* pic);
    }
```

hello.cpp

```
        HELLO_API int IntAdd(int a, int b)
        {   return a + b;
        }
        HELLO_API char* show()
        {
            return "I love U";
        }
        HELLO_API string* call_pic(char* pic)
        {   
            string a[] = {"show example","search picture","I write python " };//just to show an example
            return a;
        } //stack overflow tell me must add comment
        HELLO_API char** call_char()
        {
           char* a[] = { "I love myPan", "Love is wonderful ", "You are only love" };
           return a;
        }
```

Below is my python code:

```
        import ctypes  
        from ctypes import *  
        func = cdll.LoadLibrary('Hello.dll')
        ret = func.IntAdd(6,4)
        print(ret) //print  10
        str0 = func.show()
        size = -1
        str0 = ctypes.string_at(str0,size)
        print(str0)  //print  b"I love U"
        str1 = func.call_pic('22.jpg')
        str1=ctypes.string_at(str1,size)
        print(str1)  //Cann't Work!
        print(str1.decode('utf-8'))  // Cann't Work!
        str2 = func.call_char()
        print(str2.value)     //Cann't Work!
        str3 =ctypes.string_at(str2[0],size)
        print(str2.decode('utf-8'))  // Cann't Work!
```

Comment: You are returning a pointer to a local variable in your `call_pic` and `call_char` functions.   This is *undefined behavior*.  You must return something that hasn't gone out of scope when those functions are called, plain and simple.

Comment: But I need a  string[](or list which contains string in python),so how can I do ?can you give me simple code ? Thank you.

Comment: *But I need a string...* -- Whatever the case, you can't accomplish what you're doing by returning pointers to local variables.   It isn't even a Python issue why your code won't work -- your code wouldn't even work if you were working purely in C++.  So maybe you should be looking for other material that demonstrates marshaling string data from C++ to Python?

Comment: Thank you.I will try another language as you told me.